# Use Swig to pass in a pointer to a buffer results in "TypeError"

Tags: python, c, swig

We have an embedded system that performs processing on a buffer of data. The processing is triggered by an interrupt when the buffer is filled. The desire is to test the algorithm with simulated input data. Our data science team uses Python and the algorithm was developed in C so I offered to create a wrapper for them.

The issue revolves around pointers to buffers being passed into the algorithm.

As a simple example, the C function looks something like this:

```
float FakeCalc( unsigned int *dataBuffer,
                 float *calcSpace,
                 int    arg1,
                 float  arg2,
                 int    arg3,
                 int    arg4,
                 int   *intermediateResults
               );
```

I created a SWIG interface file as follows:

```
%module fakeCalc

%include "typemaps.i"
%apply unsigned int * INPUT { unsigned int * dataBuffer };
%apply float * INOUT { float * calcSpace };
%apply int * OUTPUT { int * intermediateResults };

%{
extern float FakeCalc( unsigned int * dataBuffer,
                 float * calcSpace,
                 int     winAvgSz,
                 float   eleMulSign,
                 int     denomWindNum,
                 int     winSz,
                 int   * intermediateResults
               );
%}

extern float FakeCalc( unsigned int * dataBuffer,
                 float * calcSpace,
                 int     winAvgSz,
                 float   eleMulSign,
                 int     denomWindNum,
                 int     winSz,
                 int   * intermediateResults
               );
```

This creates the interface so I figured I was good to go.

A simple test implementation in python before handing it off looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python 

from numpy import zeros
from array import array

import sys

import fakeCalc

def printHelp():
    print "testRun.py dataFile"

# Buffer to pass into method for scratch space
scratchBuf = zeros(10)

# Read in data to pass into method
if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    printHelp()
    exit()

dataFile = open(sys.argv[1], "r")

dataArr = array("I")

for dataPoint in dataFile:
    dataArr.append(int(dataPoint[0:-1]))

# Run calculations
fakeCalc.FakeCalc(dataArr, scratchBuf, 10, 10.5, 10, 10)
```

A couple of things to note. I can't change the arguments of the function as it's legacy code used in several code bases. The lack of buffer sizes, while obviously not ideal, is handled as the buffers are fixed when the hardware is initialized.

The buffer passed in by calcSpace is used as scratch space by the algorithm, the intermediateResults contain results of some intermediate steps internally, and the dataBuffer is just raw data and is not changed.

Currently I am getting 
    TypeError: in method 'FakeCalc', argument 1 of type 'unsigned int'

So the question in a nutshell:
Is it possible to allocate these buffers in Python and pass into C?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

A simple means to allocate a buffer from python and pass it in is to use 'carrays' provided by swig. Here is an example:

```
%module processBuffer

%include "stdint.i"
%include "carrays.i"

%array_class(uint32_t, buffer);

%{
    void processBuffer(unsigned int * buffer);
%}

void processBuffer(unsigned int * buffer);
```

In python, create the buffer and pass in the pointer in the following manner:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import processBuffer

buffer = []

for x in range (0, 10):
    buffer.append(x)

print buffer

test = processBuffer.buffer(10);
for x in range (0, 10):
    test[x] = buffer[x]

processBuffer.processBuffer(test.cast())
```

So far no issues with this approach.

For some background for those interested, looking at the generated code the original issue became clear. Passing in a pointer SWIG makes the assumption that a single object is being passed. To do so a temporary object is created to avoid type incompatibilities. This breaks down with arrays. There are more complicated solutions that also work creating custom typemaps, but the above solution is much simpler.